# CD/ DVD/ Blu-Ray Device Undectable

Tags: hardware, mount

I can't get my fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 to recognize that I've got a drive for CDs, DVDs, and Blu-Rays...

Here's the output of a couple of commonly-requested terminal commands in other forum posts I've read on the topic:

```
$ ls -l /dev/{cd,dvd}\*
ls: cannot access /dev/cd*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /dev/dvd*: No such file or directory

$ sudo lshw -c disk
  *-disk:0
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST9250421ASG
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: DE12
       serial: 5TH00M12
       size: 232GiB (250GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00099b7e
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST9250421ASG
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: DE12
       serial: 5TH00HHY
       size: 232GiB (250GB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5

$ sudo lshw -c drive
```

Additionally, here's my fstab file:

```
\# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
\#
\# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
\# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
\# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
\#
\# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
\# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3112a024-7483-447b-9069-c6d0b5ed23d4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
\# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5742166e-368f-4374-b188-a1ce61faadaa none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Sorry, I really don't know much about the Linux auto-detect/ mount process.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, apparently Ubuntu doesn't detect the type of connection I have by default...after installing all updates to the OS, it autodetects and mounts appropriately.

My bad.